# Difference between Get-IISSite and Get-ChildItem iis:\\sites

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering if someone can explain to me a difference in behavior that I'm seeing.

I'm trying to find the physical path of an IIS site.

This sample works, correctly returning the PhysicalPath

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-ChildItem iis:\\sites | Select PhysicalPath
```

This sample doesn't work. The PhysicalPath is returned as null / empty.

```
Get-IISSite | select PhysicalPath
```

If I'm correct, both the samples should be returning a `Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site` object. Why is the second one missing data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see:

**Get-ChildItem iis:\sites | get-Member | Where name -like p* | Sort-Object Name**

```
    TypeName: System.Object

 Name          MemberType   Definition
 ----          ----------   ----------
 password      NoteProperty string password=
 physicalPath  NoteProperty string physicalPath=C:\inetpub\wwwroot
 PSChildName   NoteProperty string PSChildName=Default Web Site
 PSDrive       NoteProperty PSDriveInfo PSDrive=IIS
 PSIsContainer NoteProperty bool PSIsContainer=True
 PSParentPath  NoteProperty string PSParentPath=WebAdministration::\\SANKNIGHT\Sites
 PSPath        NoteProperty string PSPath=WebAdministration::\\SANKNIGHT\Sites\Default Web Site
 PSProvider    NoteProperty IIsProviderInfo PSProvider=WebAdministration
```

**Get-IISSite | get-Member**

```
    TypeName: Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site

 Name                       MemberType            Definition
 ----                       ----------            ----------
 ApplicationDefaults        Property              Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationDefaults ApplicationDefault...
 Applications               Property              Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationCollection Applications {get;}
 Attributes                 Property              Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationAttributeCollection Attri...
 Bindings                   Property              Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection Bindings {get;}
 ChildElements              Property              Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationChildElementCollection Ch...
 Delete                     Method                void Delete()
```

it doesn't have any members starting with P and has far fewer members than Get-ChildItem. You can see they are not the same object either.

When using Get-ChildItem, each provider provides some hints on what should be displayed. I think this is in:

`$pshome\Modules\WebAdministration\iisprovider.format.ps1xml`

because of this, all the extra information is added.

Comment: Yes, and for the output of "Get-IISSite" the PhysicalPath is derived from `$_.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath`

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct, but seemed convoluted to get there. The shorter answer is they are returning different object types.

Hopefully this illustrates it better:

```
$PSDriveThing = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites\
$IISSiteThing = Get-IISSite
```

Both objects are Arrays, but the contents are vastly different, and the object `get-iisSite` returns doesn't surface a PhysicalPath object at the top level. So when you `select` for something that doesn't exist, you're creating an empty array.

```
    > $PSDriveThing

    physicalPath
    ------------
    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
    D:\web\OurPortalWeb\site

    > $IISSiteThing
    PhysicalPath
------------
```

Now instead, get the actual IIS objects:

```
> $IISSiteThing = Get-IISSite
> $IISSiteThing

Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Stopped    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
                                                                net.msmq localhost
                                                                msmq.formatname localhost
                                                                net.pipe *

OurPortalWeb    2    Started    D:\web\OurPortalWeb\site        https *:443:portal-test2.contoso.com sslFlags=None
```

There's two sites, so two object, so we'll grab the first one at array index 0:

```
>$IISSiteThing[0]
Name             ID   State      Physical Path                  Bindings
----             --   -----      -------------                  --------
Default Web Site 1    Stopped    %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot  http *:80:
                                                                net.msmq localhost
                                                                msmq.formatname localhost
                                                                net.pipe *
                                                                net.tcp 808:*
```

And as you drill down the object, you'll find lots of sub-nodes and info in the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement`, until eventually you find you want:

```
> $IISSiteThing[0].Applications[0].VirtualDirectories[0].PhysicalPath
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
```

One way to grab just the physical paths as you wanted would be:

```
> Get-IISSite | % {$_.Applications} | % {$_.VirtualDirectories} | % {$_.PhysicalPath}
%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
D:\web\OurPortalWeb\site
```